# Is there a way to analyze the elements in a material from a satellite?

Tags: x-rays

There are means to analyze elements in a specimen in a laboratory, such as XRF and PIXE.  My question is this - is there a way to analyze elements in a specimen from a satellite?
Edit:  to clarify, I'm referring to large solid objects observed in Antarctica, so remote that direct sampling (also contact-XRF) is extremely difficult. Even obtaining a small sample from such an object is a daunting challenge to scientists.  Can such solid objects be analyzed for elemental content, from a satellite?

Comment: Astronomical satellites equipped with spectroscopy equipment do it all the time, studying the stars.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: It really depends on what the specimen is.